# Slicing of a list is not working when range is being used on 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
my_list = range(1, 11)

print(my_list[::2]) 

>>> range(1,11,2)
```

Its not displaying the correct output which should be [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

Comment: `range` does not produce a list, no.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#ranges

Comment: [`range()` doesn't return a list in Py3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On python3.x, `range` returns a `range` object rather than a list.  Slicing the range object just returns another range object which is what is displaying in your terminal:

```
>>> range(1, 11)[::2]
range(1, 11, 2)
>>> type(range(1, 11)[::2])
<class 'range'>
```

However, iterating over the result should produce the desired elements:

```
>>> list(range(1, 11)[::2])
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```